# Space availability on disc

Tags: linux, debian, disk-usage

I run Debian 6 linux located on SD card. Trying to extract  tar.gz  file to /opt directory , but system complains regarding no space available on disc.
Command `df -k` brings:

```
user@ion:/opt$ df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                   984112         0    984112   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                     10240        24     10216   1% /dev
tmpfs                   984112         0    984112   0% /dev/shm
rootfs                  499640    474856         0 100% /
/dev/mmcblk0p2         1998608    321344   1677264  17% /usr
/dev/mmcblk0p3         1998608    198188   1800420  10% /var
/dev/mmcblk0p4         2938992    249096   2689896   9% /home
```

Please correct my understanding below.
I see that `rootfs` fully used and it is for root directory `/`. And since `/opt` is placed in this location it is true that there is no space available. I'm right?

How to know which file is biggest in my system?

UPD

After I deleted some files in ~ directory, I still cant extract to `/opt/`. Just several files are extracted.

I can extract all files to `~` folder. Why I can extract to `~` and not `/opt/` folder? How to fix it?

Comment: You can extract to `~`, your home directory in the home partition, where there is available space, but if `/opt` is in `/`, the root partition, which is full, you cannot extract into that directory.

Answer (score 3):

Your `/opt` directory is on the root filesystem.  Your root filesystem is full.

Your `/home` directory is on its own filesystem.  Your home directory is not full.

For answers to your question about finding large files, see the duplicates to [your recent similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451431).

Comment: How to increase root filesystem's size?

Comment: @vico See, for example, https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+how+to+increase+root+debian

Answer (score 0):

## Finding what is using your disk space

Use `k4dirstat` or `baobab`, they are graphical tools, that will help you discover what is using up space. Warning it will tell you that `/usr` and a few other system dirs are using a lot of space, but little about which apps. However for you these are separate mounts.

## Move `/opt`

Your `/` is tiny. You have `/usr` and `/var` on separate mounts so this may not be a problem, except that `/opt` is part of `/` (I assume).

You can move `/opt` to `/home/opt`, and then replace `/opt` with a symlink to `/home/opt`.

mv -T /opt /home/opt
  ln -s -t / /home/opt

### Caviets

If you `/home` is mounted noexec (or nosuid or maybe some others), then it will not work without also doing a bind mount, to add these permissions.